# Python pyqt - determine if signal is emitted by user action

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a `QtableView` which column are resized when new data is added. User can also change the column width by direct interaction with the `horizontalHeader` (click-drag). Both events emit the signal `QtableView.horizontalHeader().sectionResized()`.

I would like to determine if this signal was emitted by the user changing the column width or by a refresh from a function call. How can I distinguish the events?

I tried using `sender()` but both action refer to the same sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you must do yourself - there is no magic method for it.

It would probably be possible to subclass `QHeaderView` and monitor the various user-initiated events that may trigger a resize, but that kind of solution might be hard to get right. A much simpler and more obvious solution would be to set a flag when new data is being added to the table and unset it once the columns have been resized. Then you can check the flag inside any slots connected to the `sectionResized` signal to see what triggered it:

```
def updateTable(self):
    self._updating = True
    # add new data...
    # resize columns...
    self._updating = False

def handleSectionResized(self):
    if self._updating:
        print('updating')
    else:
        print('user interaction')
```